# Extracting specific text from a text file in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I'm having some problems with UNIX shell scripting, specifically file reading. What I would like the end product to be is for the script to take a text file as a command line argument and then extract certain parts to use in various operations. The text file would look like this:

```
ABC12345:John Smith:78
DEF12345:Jane Doe:80
GHI12345:Bob Johnson:91
```

and it would continue like that with several other lines. Now what I have done so far to extract the number after the last colon is here in this code snippet:

```
case $1 in

   m)cat $2 | while read -r file; do
   #gets the numbers from 0 to 100
   current=grep [0-100]
```

The case statement is just because in the end the user will be able to run the program different ways. The main idea in the code segment however is to take the 2-digit number at the end of the line in the text file and store it in the current variable.

The rest of the operations really revolve around this idea, however, I'm not entirely sure how to extract the name in the middle.

Anyway, any help would be great! Just please keep in mind I am very new to this.

Comment: You should take a look at awk or cut. It lets you print out columns.  To get the name in the middle, it could be as simple as cut -d: -f2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string based on delimiter in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/split-string-based-on-delimiter-in-bash)

Answer (score 1):

As frankc suggests, awk or cut would work well. You could also fiddle with `IFS` and (assuming Bash) arrays:

```
_old_ifs="$IFS"
IFS=":"
ID_NAME_GRADE=( $LINE )
IFS="$_old_ifs"

echo "Hello ${ID_NAME_GRADE[1]}, your grade is ${ID_NAME_GRADE[2]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ while IFS=: read a b c; do echo $c; done < input.txt
```

That will echo the third field of each line.  Modify to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to extract name and score in your case. see example:

```
kent$  cat t
ABC12345:John Smith:78
DEF12345:Jane Doe:80
GHI12345:Bob Johnson:91

#using awk 
kent$  awk -F: '{print "name="$2,", score="$3}' t                                         
name=John Smith , score=78
name=Jane Doe , score=80
name=Bob Johnson , score=91

#using cat
kent$  sed -r 's/[^:]*?:([^:]*):([0-9]*)$/name=\1, score=\2/g' t
name=John Smith, score=78
name=Jane Doe, score=80
name=Bob Johnson, score=91

#or just catch it directly with grep
kent$  grep -Po  "(?<=:)[^:]*(?=:)|(?<=:)\d+$" t
John Smith
78
Jane Doe
80
Bob Johnson
91
```

cut can do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

AWk -F: '{print $NF}' file_name